# How do you target a paragraph using the href attribute within a link inside of it with just css?

Tags: css-selectors

I have a bunch of paragraphs that I want to line-indent.  They all have a link inside of them with the same href attribute.  I can style the text using the attribute for things like color, but I can't indent the text.  I assume that's because I need to target the paragraph and not the link but I want to avoid additional markup.  Can I target the paragraph using the href attribute in the link somehow with just css?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like

```
<p>Some text with <a href="knownLink.html">a link</a></p>
```

and you want to style the whole paragraph. Unfortunately, [CSS does not have "parent" selectors](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).